# in SQL EXPLAIN, Possible Keys and Key, Do I select one of PK or all?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I've been trying to use SQL `EXPLAIN` lately, And there is something werid with the PK `Possible Keys` and K `Key`,

I get for example the following row

```
[id - select_type - table - type  -   possible_keys   -   key    - key_len - ref   - rows - Extra]
[1  -   PRIMARY   - users - const - PRIMARY, username - username -   66    - const -   1  - using index; using temporary; using filesort]
```

What i understood that i must pick both `PRIMARY` and `username` as `multiple index`, But i can only have one `PRIMARY` key at the table for `id`, So does `PK` shows me keys that i'm supposed to select one of them?

Comment: The idea of key is to make lookup faster in database, pk is also key but used typically for reference with other table. I guess PK means primary key.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ in some tables i get `key = NULL` and `possible_keys = PRIMARY, column`, And i guess `NULL` key is bad, If i tried to make a multiple index from both `PRIMARY, column` both `possible_keys` and `keys` become `NULL`, What does that mean?

Comment: You can not convert a field to key if it contains null, if it should be something else than l hope someone can add more in comments as I am out on mobile device right now

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ i don't convert it, it doesn't exist, so `key` is `NULL`, but PK`PRIMARY, Column` exists, If i made a key of `Column` the result becomes PK`PRIMARY, Column` Key`Column`.

Comment: Ok I got you it is out of my thinking scope at this moment, if I come of something I will added that

Answer (score 3):

*You* don't "pick an index" to use in a query; the Optimizer picks.

A `PRIMARY KEY` (PK) can have one or more columns in it.  A table can have only one PK.  Every table should have a PK.

A "secondary key" is any index other than the PK.  It, too, can have one or more columns.

The Optimizer almost never uses more than one index (PK or some secondary) for a single `SELECT`.

"Possible keys" is those that the Optimizer thinks *might* work.  After further analysis, it decides which one to use, and declares it in the "key" column.  In your example, the Optimizer decided that `INDEX "username" (...)` would work better than `PRIMARY KEY(...)`.

I am unclear on what you expect "multiple index" to mean...

- There can be multiple indexes; but the Optimizer is unlikely to use more than one.
- An index may have multiple columns in it.
- A table can have multiple indexes.

The Optimizer has a fall-back:  Simply scan the entire table (without touching any of the indexes).

If you want to discuss `EXPLAINs` further, please show us both the `SELECT` and the `EXPLAIN`.  And show more than one pair, so we can 'compare and contrast'.